# (cantilever) gas sensor with MOS technology - How does it work?

Tags: sensor, cmos, gas

I'm having trouble understanding how the gas sensor with MOS technology works. I cannot find a study material with the basic principles of operation. I can find some subjects, but with information such as too deep knowledge, I have no in-depth knowledge on the subject.
Could someone please explain give me a link, document (PDF) that talks about this subject in a fundamental way how it works?

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused: the figure you show looks like it's from some basic educational material that you claim you can't find? I'd expect the text you took this from to explain it. If you don't understand that text, maybe cite it (and link to it) and explain what specific question you have instead?

Comment: it really seems, but it is taken from a scientific article, speaks in depth, I cannot understand.

Comment: 1. link to that article (quite obvious I find), 2. such articles always link to basic articles 3. again, if you don't understand something, ask about it, specifically.

Comment: What is your background? Because from the picture it's pretty obvious that the special materials sticks to the gas molecules and changes the mass which changes the resonant frequency. That is about a basic explanation as you will get.

Comment: the picture seems to describe a simple mechanical system .... similar to a wooden school ruler that is clamped, at one end, to a table .... strumming the free end of the ruler results in a sound, with the pitch being dependent on the length of the ruler ... sticking a small mass to the ruler lowers the frequency of the sound that is produced

Comment: I had seen that, but I cannot understand how it ends up influencing the MOSFET case together with the cantilevers. So my question. (gas sensor with MOS technology)

Comment: You mean how the resonant frequency of the beam is probably measured via capacitance due to changing position of the beam away from some surface? Like in MEMS gyros or accelerometers?

Comment: I will tell you what I understand. when we have the resonant cavities in the case of this cantilever device, when there is a molecule on the surface of this device, it will respond at a certain frequency. That way we will know what substance is on the surface of the device. Because it will vibrate at that frequency x.

Comment: My problem is: I cannot understand this relationship with the mosfet when we deal with gas sensors, I cannot understand the basic principle associated with the mosfet device (attention I know how the mosfet works). I can't find a simple relationship about understanding (explanation of the subject).

Comment: "My problem is: I cannot understand this relationship with the mosfet" then you are probably looking for application notes for these sensors. Their makers' websites should have something.

Comment: MOS just means metal oxide silicon. It just means it can be built on a similar process as MOSFETs. It does not mean that the entire sensor is a MOSFET.

Comment: @LUFER add all that you already understand **to your question** instead of just as comment. This is crucial to you asking an answerable question.

Comment: look through these ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cantilever+sensor&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @ Marcus Müller...It is difficult to answer my questions, because I do not speak English, so there may be a failure in communication. I'm trying my best to translate for you. I will try one more time. I don't know how a cantilever gas sensor with MOS technology works. How do the two work together?

Comment: @LUFER **EDIT YOUR QUESTION TO INCLUDE WHAT YOU'VE UNDERSTOOD**. Don't just post more comments. I said this multiple times now.